# Sending multiple values with python requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

Good morning,
Once i have used requests for submitting a web-form with only one value / parameter. But now i have to submit a web-form with multiple values but its not submitting and the print(r.status_code, r.reason) is 200,OK. There is not any error. I have searched a lot but i'm not understanding what's wrong. Here is my code.

```
import requests

payload = {'to':'anyemail@xx.com','from':'anyemail@xx.com','message':'sent from python','subject':'sent from python'}
r = requests.post("http://www.website.com/send.php",data=payload)
print('Email sent successfully!')    
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
print(r.text)
print(r.content)
```

webpage code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="send.php">
            <input type="email" name="to">
            <input type="email" name="from">
            <input type="text" name="message">
            <input type="text" name="subject">
            <input type="submit" name="send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You [give the values as a list](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

Comment: You should also be aware that everybody could use your send.php to send mails like that. Its like a free spam service.

Comment: Philip : I'm not that stupid Don't worry about it
1) This page will be in deep web.
2) All the content on that page is invisible.

Comment: I used to use `submit` as an additional parameter when constructing urls from forms. Does adding `'submit':True` or `'send':True` to the `payload` help?

Comment: Klaus D : Why i should use as list. I'm sending one value for one input.

Comment: Chilie : I'm using the same method for submitting another form and its working. The only difference is that this form have multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting the content type:

```
url = '.....'
payload = {'to':'anyemail@xx.com','from':'anyemail@xx.com','message':'sent from python','subject':'sent from python'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

The content Type defines how the Webserver is interpreting your post data.
Make sure you are using the correct content Type.

Comment: Not working, Currently its this content type ISO-8859-1

Comment: ISO-8859-1 is no content type its an encoding or charset. A content type defines the way to read the content for example: Xml, Json, Csv, Text, Html, CSS, Js, or Media like mp3 mp4 ogg, or binarys like zip, rar, 7zip and so on. But the Encoding it only the way hot to read text. That means if the content type is a text based data type like xml json html javascript or just plain text the encoding tells us how to interpret the bytes into characters. Depending on the encoding a character contains 1 or multiple bytes which is needed if you want to include special chars like in some asian langs.

Comment: Using a different encoding can of course also cause problems.

Comment: Philip : Thanks for the information. I have solved the problem using the $_GET instead of $_POST but i still need an answer for curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

There are many times that you want to send data that is not form-encoded. If you pass in a string instead of a dict, that data will be posted directly by using json.dumps(payload)

```
import requests,json

payload = {'to':'anyemail@xx.com','from':'anyemail@xx.com','message':'sent from python','subject':'sent from python'}
r = requests.post("http://www.website.com/send.php",data=json.dumps(payload))
print('Email sent successfully!')    
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
print(r.text)
print(r.content)
```

Comment: Tried. Not the solution. :( . The worst thing is that i can't see any error so i can search it.